# How to add claims to use them inside identityserver

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm writing an app that uses identityserver (an MVC and several APIs + IS). I needed some custom claims so i've added them using customprofileservice. It's working, claims are inside the access token and i can use them inside API or MVC. But i don't have this claims inside identity server while trying to make user's personal page. How i can use this claims inside IS?

Comment: What do you mean by `Claims are not available in IS`? Does that mean you want to secure action which has been written in one of IS controller? If that is the case you should secure IS itself first using [AddLocalApiAuthentication](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html) so you would be able to access claims from the `User` object.

Comment: Yes, I have IS4 with protected controllers. And inside this contrlles i can't get claims. I'l try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Well i've tried a whole lot of things but still couldn't get claims inside of the identityserver controller. Are there any other ways to add custom claims?